# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' Trainer.train() error

Tags: python, nlp, multilabel-classification, huggingface-datasets, huggingface-trainer

I am trying to encode string labels as numerical values to be used for training

I load the dataset below and get just the labels columns

```
dataset = load_dataset("csv", data_files="dataset")
features = dataset["train"].column_names
features.remove("comment")
```

the functions below is for encoding the labels (3 different labels in total)

```
def labels(label):
  return ['Women', 'Black', 'Muslim'].index(label)

def encode_labels(record):
   #print(record)
   return {"labels": labels(record[feature]) for feature in features}


dataset = dataset.map(encode_labels)
```

below is the code for running the Trainer

```
from sentence_transformers.losses import CosineSimilarityLoss
from setfit import SetFitTrainer

trainer = SetFitTrainer(
model=model,
train_dataset=train_dataset,
eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
loss_class=CosineSimilarityLoss,
num_iterations=20,
column_mapping={"comment": "text", "labels": "label"},)

Trainer.train()
```

The error below is produced from the training:

```
Applying column mapping to training dataset
Generating Training Pairs: 100%
20/20 [00:00<00:00, 105.97it/s]
***** Running training *****
Num examples = 5080
Num epochs = 1
Total optimization steps = 318
Total train batch size = 16
Epoch: 100%
1/1 [00:24<00:00, 24.36s/it]
Iteration: 100%
318/318 [00:24<00:00, 13.16it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-3435b262f1ae> in <cell line: 1>()
 ----> 1 trainer.train()

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in _unique_multiclass(y)
 26         return xp.unique_values(xp.asarray(y))
 27     else:
---> 28         return set(y)
 29 
 30 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: I don't think it's the problem, but what's the line `return {"labels": labels(record[feature]) for feature in features}` supposed to be doing.  It looks like you're putting multiple items in a dictionary, but they all have the same key, so they're going to overwrite each other if there's more than one.  And do you have a full stack backtrace?